# Why does find . -not -name ".*" not exclude hidden files?

Tags: bash, replace, find

I want to ignore all hidden files, but especially .git and .svn ones when searching (and later replacing) files, not I have found that the most basic way to exclude such hidden files described in many online tutorials doesn't work here.

```
find . -not -name ".*"
```

will also print hidden files.

The script I'm trying to write is

```
replace() {
    if [ -n "$3" ]; then expr="-name \"$3\""; fi
    find . -type f \( $expr -not -name ".*" \) -exec echo sed -i \'s/$1/$2/g\' {} \;
    unset expr
}
```

Comment: `find . -not -name ".*"` works to me.

Comment: Use `find . -not -name '.*'`, to avoid shell expansion.

Comment: to be precise, it still finds (non hidden) files in hidden directories.

Comment: @Rubens You are thinking of parameter expansion; globs are not expanded inside double quotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing is `-not -name ".*"` does match all files and directories that start with anything but "." - but it doesn't prune them from the search, so you'll get matches from inside hidden directories. To prune paths use `-prune`, i.e.:

```
find $PWD -name ".*" -prune -o -print
```

(I use `$PWD` because otherwise the start of the search "." would also be pruned and there would be no output)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still a little lost - why does `find $PWD -name '.*' -prune -o -name '*.c' -type f -print` work but not `find $PWD -name '.*' -prune -o $expr -type f -print` with `expr="-name '*.c'"`?

Comment: The quotes you embed in the value of `expr` are not removed after `expr` is expanded; they are treated literally.

Comment: Also consider `find . -path "*/.*" -prune -o -print`, which works and prints relative paths.

Comment: NB. When using `-prune`, you shouldn't leave off the `-print` at the end as you normally would, as it changes the semantics of the command when used with `-prune`.

Answer (score 0):

correct version

```
replace() {
        if [ -n "$3" ]; then expr=-name\ $3; fi
        find $PWD -name '.*' -prune -o $expr -type f -exec sed -i s/$1/$2/g {} \;
        unset expr
}
```