# Exclude hidden files and folders in linux find

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am trying to exclude hidden files and folders when doing a `find` in linux.

I have to exclude files or folders that start with a dot (.hidden) but also have to exclude folders that start with an @ (like @eaDir).

So far I have the following command which seems to work but maybe there is a more elegant way?

```
find /path/to/start/search/ -not -path '*@eaDir*' -not -path "*/\.*" -type f -mtime -2
```

I did see examples using regular expression like so:

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f
```

but not sure how I would also exclude `@eaDir` directories with the `-regex`option?

I believe there can also be hidden files that start with two dots? like "..hidden"? Is this already covered with my command or would I simply add a third option like `-not -path "*/\..*"` to exclude those as well?

Then I saw some examples of using `-prune` so that find won't descend in hidden directories, however I am unsure how I would use this correclty in my example. I would be interested in this to speed things up.

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [Count files, except the hidden files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52621332/608639) and [Why does find . -not -name “.*” not exclude hidden files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16900675/608639)

Answer (score 8):

Exclude files and folders starting with a `.` or an `@`:

```
find /path/to/start/search/ -not -path '*/[@.]*' -type f -mtime -2
```

Exclude files starting with a `.` and files and folders starting with a `.` or an `@`:

```
find /path/to/start/search/ -not -path '*/.*' -type f -mtime -2 | grep -v '/@.*/.*'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great and is much more sleek than my initial command! Now I just need to figure out about the `-prune` option.

Comment: `find /path/to/start/search/ -prune -not -name '.*' -type f -mtime -2 | grep -v '/@.*/.*` I guess? (untested)

Answer (score 6):

Use `-not -name '.*'`. This will exclude any names that begin with `.`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but this doesn't work for me e.g.
  **$ find . -type d -not -name ".*"**
includes files in hidden directories, as does
  **$ find . -not -path '*/[@.]*' -type f**
Maybe it's because of my old version of find... v4.4.2, 2007

Comment: This works for me
**find . -type d \( -path "\*/.\*" \) -prune -o -name '*.txt' -print** but it's complicated to remember...

Comment: My answer is just excluding the files and directories that are returned, not the directories that are descended into. So it won't return `.foo`, but it will return `.foo/bar`

Comment: @Barmar `man find` -> use `-path` or `-wholename`.